# Can I host a Nuget Package built in .Net Core using Nuget.Server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, nuget

Nuget.Server use .NET Framework 4.6.1

Can I host a Nuget Package built with .Net Core in an ASP.NET Application created with Nuget.Server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The Nuget.Server just hosts the packages and doesn't care for the content of the packages as long as the packages contain nuspecs.